# Three.js - Margin renderer across the screen

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I move the renderer on the screen. For example, like margin-left:300px for divs.
renderer code:

```
function initRenderer() {
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
renderer.setClearColor( 0xff0000 );}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move the entire element containing the scene? Just move the canvas element the renderer is inside using css. Otherwise you can move the camera inside the scene to shift the view.

Comment: Thanks bro. This gave me the solution var r = renderer.domElement and then r.style....

Comment: Render is not a object in 3D, you cant move render in scene. You can use CSS on Canvas or Canvas parent.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am really new in Three.js and 3D and any advice is appreciated!